# java -jar app.jar leads to NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while IDE run works fine

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

trying to run jar file of a spring boot application . working with gradle and ran the gradle build job in Intellij to create the jar.
when running the application from the IDE everything works fine and when i'm running

```
java -jar app.jar
```

i'm getting the NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. what could be the reason?

build. gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:4.0.0'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    enabled = true
    archiveClassifier.set("")
    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.example.players.PlayersApplication"
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

output of gradle build job:

```
5:43:46 PM: Executing 'build'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :resolveMainClassName
> Task :bootJar
> Task :jar
> Task :assemble
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses

> Task :test
2023-04-25T17:44:26.265+03:00  INFO 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-25T17:44:26.267+03:00  INFO 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2023-04-25T17:44:26.485+03:00  INFO 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-04-25T17:44:26.505+03:00  INFO 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-04-25T17:44:26.511+03:00  INFO 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-25T17:44:26.512+03:00  INFO 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2023-04-25T17:44:26.528+03:00  WARN 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90121, SQLState: 90121
2023-04-25T17:44:26.530+03:00 ERROR 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-214]
2023-04-25T17:44:26.537+03:00  WARN 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 90121, SQLState: 90121
2023-04-25T17:44:26.537+03:00 ERROR 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-214]
2023-04-25T17:44:26.540+03:00  WARN 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to release JDBC Connection used for DDL execution
2023-04-25T17:44:26.541+03:00  INFO 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-04-25T17:44:26.543+03:00  INFO 2092 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Shutdown completed.

> Task :check
> Task :build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 39s
7 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 2 up-to-date
5:44:26 PM: Execution finished 'build'.
```

output of java -jar app.jar:

```
17:37:23.186 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'playersController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'playersService': E
rror creating bean with name 'playersService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'playersRepository': No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.players.repositories.Players
Repository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713)    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293)
        at com.example.players.PlayersApplication.main(PlayersApplication.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'playersService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'playersRep
ository': No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.players.repositories.PlayersRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotat
ions: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:713)    
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:693)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:710)    
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell from here. You need to share code of `PlayerController`, `Player` entity and `PlayerService`

Comment: @Demir added to original question

Comment: The way you are building the jar doesn't look right to me. Excluding duplicates will result in jar entries being lost, including the `META-INF/spring/*` files that Boot relies upon. Why not use the `bootJar` task that Boot's Gradle plugin provides?

Comment: @Shahar can you share `Player`entity? I think you missed it.

Comment: i removed the duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE) and it solved it. thank you so much!

Comment: Remove your `jar` task and re-run. This will let Spring Boot generate the proper jar for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Andy Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384297/andy-wilkinson) wrote in a comment,

> The way you are building the jar doesn't look right to me. Excluding duplicates will result in jar entries being lost, including the `META-INF/spring/*` files that Boot relies upon.

Followed by the suggestion to use the `bootJar` task that Boot's Gradle plugin provides.

Subsequently, the question author, [Shahar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21526371/shahar), removed `duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)` and that solved it.